# How to save a list into a zip archive in R?

Tags: r, gzip

I want to save each element of a list as a txt file and save all of txt files in a zip folder. I was able to create a function that currently saves element of the list into a txt file. Sample list could look like this:

[image]

I found that `gzfile` and `readr` allow creating zip for a single file. For eg

```
write_tsv(mtcars, file.path(dir, "mtcars.tsv.gz"))
#OR
write.csv(mtcars, file=gzfile("mtcars.csv.gz"))
```

Whereas, I want to be able to create a zip folder that contains data1.txt, data2.txt and data.txt.
Are there any packages that would allow this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` from base R to zip your text files. Something like this:

```
file_names = paste0(names(your_list), ".txt")
for(i in seq_along(your_list)) {
  write_tsv(your_list[[i]], file.path(dir, file_names[i]))
}
zip(file.path(dir, "zipped_files.zip"), files = file.path(dir, file_names))
```

Comment: I tried the above code, I am getting error in last line that argument files is missing. Then I added parenthesis after `"zipped_files.zip"`. After this code ran, but no zipped folder created in my directory.
I also tried creating a vector with filenames and passed that to zip function, code runs fine in R but nothing is being created in my directory.

Comment: I tried zipping another file existing in my directory, same issue. 
`zip(zipfile = "temp.zip", files = "test.csv")
> file.info(c("temp.zip", "test.csv"))['size']
> size
temp.zip      NA
test.csv 1575313`
code runs, but it doesn't create a zip folder in the directory.

Comment: Hmmm, can you try a minimal example in your working directory? `write.csv(mtcars, "mt1.csv"); write.csv(mtcars, "mt2.csv"); zip("mt.zip", files = c("mt1.csv", "mt2.csv"))` then on my system `"mt.zip" %in% list.files()` gives `TRUE` and I can see the zip file.

Comment: I tried the example you shared, same thing, it creates csv files but doesn't create zip folder. `"mt.zip" %in% list.files(); [1] FALSE`

Comment: Are you on Windows? The `?zip` help page says *"On Windows, the default relies on a zip program (for example that from Rtools) being in the path."*. You may need to install Rtools or some command line zip function and put it on the system path. (Though annoying if that's the case that there isn't a helpful error or warning message...)

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows. I tried installing Rtools, tried a different directory. It doesn't seem to be working. May be I should also try a command line zip function.